# How to send data batch by batch to Kafka producer from CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-kafka

I'm new to scala 
I use the below code to read the data and send it to a Kafka producer

```
//Kafka properties
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers)
    properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    properties.put("client.id", clientId)

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](properties)



    val loop = new Breaks()

    //The while loop will send data to Kafka
    loop.breakable{
      while(true){

          val FileStream  = Source.fromFile(csv_file)
          for (line <- FileStream.getLines) {
          val today = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
          val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
          val key = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")(0)
          val value = formatter.format(today) + "," + line

          val data = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, value)

          //println("--- topic: " + topic + " —-")
          //println("key: " + data.key())
          //println("value: " + data.value() + "\n")
          println(data.value())
          producer.send(data)
        }
```

but what I want to do is I have a CSV with 40 records and I want to send first 10 records and then the next set of 10 records in 4 batches sequentially to a Kafka producer after a certain interval like below

```
2012-08-13T00:00:00.000Z,92.29,92.59,91.74,92.4,2075391.0,MMM
2012-08-14T00:00:00.000Z,92.36,92.5,92.01,92.3,1843476.0,MMM
2012-08-15T00:00:00.000Z,92.0,92.74,91.94,92.54,1983395.0,MMM
2012-08-16T00:00:00.000Z,92.75,93.87,92.21,93.74,3395145.0,MMM
2012-08-17T00:00:00.000Z,93.93,94.3,93.59,94.24,3069513.0,MMM

2012-08-20T00:00:00.000Z,94.0,94.17,93.55,93.89,1640008.0,MMM
2012-08-21T00:00:00.000Z,93.98,94.1,92.99,93.21,2302988.0,MMM
2012-08-22T00:00:00.000Z,92.56,93.36,92.43,92.68,2463908.0,MMM
2012-08-23T00:00:00.000Z,92.65,92.68,91.79,91.98,1823757.0,MMM
2012-08-24T00:00:00.000Z,92.03,92.97,91.94,92.83,1945796.0,MMM
```

How can we achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain why you want this artificial batching / delay? Also, have you considered using Kafka Connect for ingesting the data into Kafka instead of writing the code yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to create a data simulator which takes data from a CSV and sends it to Kafka batch by batch for every 5 seconds and no I have not considered using Kafka connect

Comment: I can't help with your scala, but if your question is more about supplying random data to Kafka I can provide an answer on that. Let me know if that would be useful

Comment: It seems odd to want to artificially batch the producer. You can still do that on the consumer.

Comment: @Thilo how can we do that on consumer